# The coprime action and A-invariant Sylow p-subgroup

Tags: normal-subgroups, sylow-theory, invariant-theory, coprime

I read the article (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291552840_Invariant_Sylow_subgroups_and_solvability_of_finite_groups )

I don't understand how easy this is:

"The group $G$ is acted on by an automorphism group $A$. If this is the coprime action ($(|A|,|G|)=1$), $G$ always has $A-$invariant Sylow $p-$subgroups for every prime $p$ (dividing the order of $G$) and there exists exactly one $A-$invariant Sylow $p-$subgroup $P$ if and only if $P$ is normalized by the ﬁxed point subgroup, $C=C_G(A)$."

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very good question indeed and it is non-trivial to prove. Here is the theorem you are after, which is the *coprime action* variant of the famous Sylow theorems.

**Theorem** Let a finite group $A$ acting via automorphisms on a finite group $G$ and assume gcd$(|A|,|G|)=1$. For every prime $p$ dividing $|G|$:
$(a)$ There exists an $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroup.
$(b)$ All $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroups are $C_G(A)$-conjugate.
$(c)$ If $P$ is an $A$-invariant subgroup of $G$, then $P$ is contained in some $A$-invariant Sylow $p$-subgroup.

There are several books where this is proved, but a very clear exposition can be found in the book *Finite Group Theory* of Marty Isaacs. The proof there makes use of a famous and often applied lemma of George Glauberman. Details can be found [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=E9kOCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA101&lpg=PA101&dq=glauberman%20lemma%20coprime%20actions&source=bl&ots=OYwG-AyIAs&sig=ACfU3U341uYupU19bpjoULCcyGyZFBX5gw&hl=nl&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi049rF9_vnAhWG5KQKHcCGBbUQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=glauberman%20lemma%20coprime%20actions&f=false) (see (3.23)Theorem and (3.24)Lemma).