# Invariant Sylow subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, invariant-theory, solvable-groups

Today, I'm reading lemma 2.2.c of [an article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/291552840_Invariant_Sylow_subgroups_and_solvability_of_finite_groups) by Antonio Beltran.

> Lemma 2.2. Suppose that A is a finite group acting coprimely on a finite group G, and let $C = C_G(A)$. Then, for every prime p,
>
> c) if $N$ is an $A$-invariant normal subgroup of $G$, then $ν_p^A (N)$ and $ν_p^A (G/N)$ divide $ν_p^A (G)$.

[image]

I don't know why "if $v_p^A(G/N)=|CN/N:N_C(P)N/N|$, which **certainly** divides $v_p^A(G)=|C:N_C(P)|$".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that $v^A_p(G/N)=|CN/N:N_C(P)N/N|=|CN:N_C(P)N|$ and that $CN=(N_C(P)N)C$. But $N_C(P) \subseteq C \cap N_C(P)N \subseteq C$, whence, see diagram, $$v^A_p(G)=|C:N_C(P)|=|C:C \cap N_C(P)N| \cdot |C \cap N_C(P)N:N_C(P)|=$$
$$v^A_p(G/N) \cdot |C \cap N_C(P)N:N_C(P)|.$$
From this you also see that $v^A_p(G)=v^A_p(G/N)$ if and only if $N \cap C \subseteq N_C(P)$.
[image]

Comment: See further https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539721/the-coprime-action-and-a-invariant-sylow-p-subgroup/3566568#3566568

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596916/a-invariant-sylow-p-subgroup/3597365#3597365 

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3527692/invariant-sylow-subgroups-and-solvability-of-finite-groups/3597648#3597648