# Number of Sylow subgroups in $p$-solvable groups - Navarro article

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, solvable-groups

This is a article which Gabriel Navarro wrote. I'm reading lemma 2.1. I see that

"By standard arguments, recall that in any coprime action, if $q$ is a prime,
then every $A$-invariant $q$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in an $A$-invariant Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$. Furthermore, any two $A$-invariant Sylow $q$-subgroups are $C$-conjugate and if $P$ $\in$ $Syl_q(G)$ is $A$-invariant, then $P \cap C \in Syl_q(C)$."

I understand that by the Sylow theorems, every $q$-subgroup of $G$ is contained in a Sylow $q$-subgroup of $G$, and that any two Sylow $q$-subgroups are conjugate

But I have no experience with coprime actions, and I don't understand the $A$-invariant counterparts.

I would also appreciate any documentation about coprime actions and their basic properties.

Thank you.

https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/2003-131-10/S0002-9939-03-06884-9/S0002-9939-03-06884-9.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a good introduction, read chapter $3E$ of [M.I. Isaacs' *Finite Group Theory*.](https://kupdf.net/download/finite-group-theory-martin-isaac_591230d6dc0d60b105959ebc_pdf) This will give you information about Sylow theory under co-prime actions. By the way, from Navarro's beautiful paper it follows that in *solvable* groups $G$ for every $H \leq G$ and every prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, $n_p(H) \mid n_p(G)$ (where $n_p(\cdot)$ denotes the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups).

Also, the following posts are useful to read:
[$A$-invariant Sylow $p$-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3596916/a-invariant-sylow-p-subgroup)
[Number of Sylow subgroups in $p$-solvable groups - paper of G. Navarro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277457/number-of-sylow-subgroups-in-p-solvable-groups-paper-of-g-navarro)
and bearing the same title but different entry:
[Number of Sylow subgroups in $p$-solvable groups - paper of G. Navarro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3277457/number-of-sylow-subgroups-in-p-solvable-groups-paper-of-g-navarro/3278135#3278135)
[The article Number of Sylow subgroups in $p$-solvable groups - paper of G. Navarro](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3583676/the-article-number-of-sylow-subgroups-in-p-solvable-groups-navarro)

Comment: Is it you @Shaun downvoting?

Comment: there isn't a downvote

Comment: @SineoftheTime There might have been a downvote that has been cancelled by upvotes. But in any case it is a convention of this forum that downvoting is anonymous, so it is not appropriate to attempt to identify downvoters.

Comment: @DerekHolt If you click on the number $1$, you can also see the number of downvoters and upvoters. Maybe someone downvoted and then retracted the vote

Comment: No, @NickyHekster; I upvoted :)

Comment: By the way, if you haven't left a comment or are otherwise not following a post, you don't get a notification from `@username`.  I only saw this because I check every new [tag:group-theory] post.

Comment: @Shaun, thanks for the +1, it was downvoted immediately after I posted it, thought I did not abide by the rules ...

Comment: And maybe this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539721/the-coprime-action-and-a-invariant-sylow-p-subgroup

Comment: @Teddy: ah yes, forgot about that one, thanks for the addition!!!